# Calculating a delayed response of a system

Tags: linear-systems

Suppose I have a system:

$$y[n] = x[n] + x[n-1] + x[0]$$

To see if this system is time-variant, we can compare $H\{x[n-1]\}$ to $y[n-1]$ and check that they are different.

I think the delayed (by 1 unit) response to $x[n]$ is:

$$y[n-1] = x[n-1] + x[n-2] + x[-1]$$

Nevertheless, I'm having *an issue understanding why*. How does the $x[0]$ term (from $y[n]$) become $x[-1]$ while calculating $y[n-1]$?

Mathematically, to calculate $y[n-1]$, I thought it would be reasonable to replace $n$ by $(n-1)$ in the equation, which would result in $y[n-1] = x[n-1] + x[n-2] + x[0]$. I mean, if $y[n]$ *response contains a constant tern* $x[0]$, I *expect this value to remain* in $y[n]$ independent of the $n$ index.
**Why that's not the case ?**

---

I also have a problem with a different system:
$$y[n] = x[2n]$$

I don't understand why this system presents a delayed response:
$$y[n-1] = x[2n - 1]$$

(instead of $y[n-1]=x[2n-2]$) and why its response to the shifted (by 1 unit) input is $H\{x[2n - 2]\}$ instead of $H\{x[2n -1]\}$.

Looks like I have doubts about how to calculate the delayed response. Can you point out to problems in my examples to help clarify it?

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/verifying-linear-time-invariance/3532#3532) useful.

Comment: I changed your question from "time-invariant systems" to "how to calculate a delayed response". A "how to verify systems time-invariance" question already exists and is linked by @Juancho (and we avoid duplicates), but if you do not understand some parts of that answer, feel free to ask about that in the comments section of that question/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/verifying-linear-time-invariance/3532#3532) @Juancho liked to is indeed very useful. To me it looks like you don't understand time invariance fully, and that answer sould clarify things.

But, concerning your questions of **getting the delayed response of the systems**:

With the first system, $y[n] = x[n] + x[n-1] + x[0]$, *you are right*. **The constant term will not change**, since it is constantly $x[0]$, and thus not dependent of $n$. The correct delayed response is:

$$y[n-1] = x[n-1] + x[n-2] + x[0]$$

You can calculate that by substituting $n$ by $m-1$ (or $n-1$, it's the same which letter you use, but it's simpler for me to use a different letter while substituting). Now, whit $n=m-1$, you have:

$$y[n] = y[m-1] = x[(m-1)] + x[(m-1)-1] + x[0] = x[m-1] + x[m-2] + x[0]$$

When you get the final result (when you can't simplify any more), you can change the variable name from $m$ to $n$ again and get the first formula above.

---

With the second system, you employ the same logic to get the delayed response. Starting from:

$$y[n] = x[2n]$$

To get a delayed response you must substitute $n$ with $m-1$ and you get:

$$n = m-1$$
$$y[n] = y[m-1] = x[2 \times (m-1)] = x[2m - 2]$$

and now you can change the variable name again to get:

$$y[n-1] = x[2n - 2]$$.

These are explanations on **how to calculate a delayed response (by 1).** Looking at a **response of a system delayed by 1** actually means that at time $n=5$, you will be looking at a response that you would normally get for $n=4$. *The system is delayed, i.e. it behaves as the original, just with some time-delay*.

To put it very simply, if I mark the delayed response by $y'[n]$, and the original by $y[n]$, this would hold:

$$y'[1] = y[0]$$
$$y'[2] = y[1]$$
$$y'[100] = y[99]$$

and more generally:

$$y'[n] = y[n-1]$$

For understanding time-invariance in systems, consult the linked question since that's precisely its topic.

---

To comment on the incorrect answers you proposed as delayed responses: they are actually **responses to a delayed input**.

What that means is that you will be feeding your *original* system with a *delayed* input. If your original input signal was $x[n]$, to get a response to a delayed input, you actually want to "feed" your system to a signal $x'[n] = x[n-1]$. Let's mark *systems response to a delayed input* with $y''[n]$ and calculate that for your first example:

$$ y''[n] = x'[n] + x'[n-1] + x'[0]$$

The system *didn't change*: It's still calculating the same operation: summing up the input at time $n$ with the input at time $n-1$ with the value of the input at time $0$. **But, the input changed!**. Substituting $x'[n] = x[n-1]$, you get:

$$ y''[n] = x[(n)-1] + x[(n-1)-1] + x[(0)-1] = x[n-1] + x[n-2] + x[-1]$$

---

To summarize, in order for a system to be time-invariant, the *response of the system delayed by $k$* should be the same as the *response of the system to the input delayed by $k$*.

In this example, we were just examining delays by $1$. What proves that the system is **not time-invariant** in you case is the fact that $y'[n] \neq y''[n]$ because you have:

$$y'[n] = y[n-1] = x[n-1] + x[n-2] + x[0]$$
$$y''[n] = x'[n] + x'[n-1] + x'[0] = x[n-1] + x[n-2] + x[-1]$$

Comment: Now, i'm even more confused because s3.11 ( pag 13 ) in MIT's signal and systems asignament solution shows how the term x[0] changes to x[-N] in the case of a shift by N units of the system response to x[n] (y[n]) :
http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/assignments/MITRES_6_007S11_hw03_sol.pdf

Considering y[n] = x[2n]
It also shows how the delayed ( by N ) response to x[n] equals y[n - N] = x[2n - N] instead of x[2n - 2N] and the response to the delayed(by N units) input is T{x[2n - 2N]} rather than T{x[2n - N]} like you guys(penelope and Juancho) mentioned.

Comment: @hnl I edited my answer with more explanations, so I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: You are absolutely right, i find it amusing that the assignment solution of a MIT's course is really wrong, but that's the reality. How can i delete my answear ?

Comment: @hnl you should have a "delete" link under all of your own posts -- both answers and questions (and an 'x' sign next to your comments)

Comment: I had to setup a password to be able to delete.I also can't voteup your answear until 15+ reputation :/ .Anyways, thanks for the hints, the x',y' notation you used, clarified the topic for me.